# Loop till last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A and B
where,
A= Days
B= Bracket which depends on A

I have made code if else

```
        Sub AA()
    If Range("A2").Value <= 0 Then
            Range("B2").Value = "Not Due"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 1 And Range("A2").Value <= 30 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "1-30 Days"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 31 And Range("A2").Value <= 90 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "31-90 Days"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 91 And Range("A2").Value <= 180 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "91-180 Days"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 181 And Range("A2").Value <= 365 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "181-365 Days"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 366 And Range("A2").Value <= 730 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "1-2 Years"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 731 And Range("A2").Value <= 1095 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "2-3 Years"
    
    ElseIf Range("A2").Value >= 1096 Then
        Range("B2").Value = "Over 3 Years"
    End If 
End sub
```

Above code works on only one cell **I need to run this code till the last row**

Thanks

Comment: if you add some sample data would help

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row.

Comment: There are myriad examples of how to do this, on SE and the [internet more broadly](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=excel+loop+till+last+row), using your exact question.  What have you tried?

Comment: Why use VBA?  This is something easily solved with a lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub subLoopRows()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngLastUsedRow As Long

    'Finding out the last used row
    lngLastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    'Loop from the first row till the last used row. Set the start row as 2 if you have a header
    For lngRow = 1 To lngLastUsedRow
        
        With ActiveSheet
            
            If .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 0 Then
            
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "Not Due"
                
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 1 _
                And .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 30 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "1-30 Days"
                
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 91 _
                And .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 180 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "91-180 Days"
                
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 181 _
                And .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 365 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "181-365 Days"
                
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 366 _
                And .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 730 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "1-2 Years"
        
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 731 _
                And .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <= 1095 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "2-3 Years"
                
            ElseIf .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value >= 1096 Then
                
                .Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "Over 3 Years"
                
            End If
        
        End With
    
    Next lngRow

End Sub
```

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not understand "the last row": it's a spreadsheet that you can fill in as you wish.
You do have the possibility to go until the last cell in your column which is filled in (in VBA this is called `.End(xlDown)` for a `Range` object), but you really need to be careful: imagine you have an Excel sheet like this one:

```
        Col1   Col2
Row1  Val1.1 Val1.2
Row2  Val2.1 Val2.2

Rowa  Vala.1 Vala.2
Rowb  Valb.1 Valb.2
```

Imagine the focus is on Val1.2. When you do `.End(xlDown)` in VBA, or you press Ctrl+Down, you will go to Val2.2, not to Valb.2. So I advise you to be very cautious with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Bracket()

Dim Cell As Range

  For Each Cell In Range("A2:A1048576")
    If Cell.Value <= 0 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Due"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 1 And Cell.Value <= 30 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1-30 Days"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 31 And Cell.Value <= 90 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "31-90 Days"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 91 And Cell.Value <= 180 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "91-180 Days"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 181 And Cell.Value <= 365 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "181-365 Days"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 366 And Cell.Value <= 730 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1-2 Years"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 731 And Cell.Value <= 1095 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "2-3 Years"
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= 1096 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "2-3 Years"
         End If
  Next Cell
 
End Sub
```